# Taking into account last iteration with takewhile (itertools)

Tags: python, csv, python-itertools

I need to iterate over the .csv until the boolean called "seguir" gets False.
The problem is that takewhile discards the last iteration and values, and I need to it since the values of the .csv in that row are relevant to my problem.

```
for line in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: seguir, lectura):
    data2 = strintodate(line[1])
    data4 = strintodate(line[2])
    if data2 < data4:
        seguir = False
    escritura.writerow([programa + 1, data2, data2, line[4]])
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with a condition that `break`s after the row is written instead:

```
for line in lectura:
    data3 = strintodate(line[1])
    data4 = strintodate(line[2])
    escritura.writerow([programa + 1, data2, data2, line[4]])
    if data2 < data4:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more elegant solution to this issue is to change the moment that
you evaluate `data2 < data4`: if you do that in the predicate of the `takewhile()`, it will allow you to include the "last" iteration in your processing. In other words, if you have 5 lines with `data2 < data4` and the sixth line has `data2 >= data4`, the `for`-loop below will execute 6 times, the last time allowing you to retain the values.

The code becomes like this:

```
data2, data4 = 2, 4
for line in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: data2 < data4, lectura):
    data2 = strintodate(line[1])
    data4 = strintodate(line[2])
    escritura.writerow([programa + 1, data2, data2, line[4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing much could you just keep a temp variable outside of your for loop that stores the previous line

```
prevLine = ""
for line in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: seguir, lectura):
    <check that prevLine is not empty string as it will be on first iteration>
    <do oepration involving prevLine>
    data3 = strintodate(line[1])
    data4 = strintodate(line[2])
    if data2 < data4:
        seguir = False
    escritura.writerow([programa + 1, data2, data2, line[4]])
    prevLine = line
```

Answer (score 0):

[blhsing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55402428/753731) solution is the way to go however there's one more way to skin the cat - use `itertools.tee` to create an iterator that follows closely behind

```
iter1, iter2 = tee(lectura)
for line in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: seguir, iter1):
    next(iter2)
    data3 = strintodate(line[1])
    data4 = strintodate(line[2])
    if data2 < data4:
        seguir = False
    escritura.writerow([programa + 1, data2, data2, line[4]])
line = next(iter2)
data3 = strintodate(line[1])
data4 = strintodate(line[2])
escritura.writerow([programa + 1, data2, data2, line[4]])
```

In one word, ugly. Somewhat salvageable by extracting the setting of `data2` and other elements as well as the call to `writerow` into a separate function